# uiappearance for UIButton also changes UIBarButton image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I am using this piece of code

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To change the appearance of `UIButton`s. This works nicely and does not affect `UIBarButtonItem`s except for one of them (The only one that is not an auto generated "back" button) and only initially. When you touch the barbutton, it reverts back to not having a background image.

The problematic button is a `UIBarButton` and not an `UIButton` (Unless it is both, in which case the other `UIBarButton`s should be affected too).

A clue can be that the other `UIBarButton` that are not affected are all generated and not created by me in the storyboard.

This must be a bug in the api?

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the `UIBarButtonItem`s?

Comment: Alas as I tried to convey they are defined in the storyboard so they might as well be generated by some voodoo magic. The way I solved it was using setTintColor. The only code needed should be that one line in the app delegate and a storyboard with some navigation examples. This is really old but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `setTintColor`. Was an api bug that since then probably has been fixed